# NullReferenceException on push_back

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, nullreferenceexception, push-back

I am getting a nullReferenceException when using vector.push_back on a new object.

In the code segment you see I have the vector object as a pointer but I originally had it as a non-pointer, I changed it in my troubleshooting out of desperation.

I stepped through the instantiation of BasicSolver completely to make sure the were no issues in it and also separated the instantiation from the push_back to help show that push_back is where the problem is occurring.

InformedSolver1&2 are children of BasicSolver. vector is included in BasicSolver and therefore in puzzleSolver also.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "puzzleSolver.h"


PuzzleSolver::PuzzleSolver()
{
   solvers = new vector<BasicSolver*>();
}

void PuzzleSolver::createPuzzle(string input)
{                                             //hitting step-over
   BasicSolver* temp = new BasicSolver(input);// no errors
   solvers->push_back(temp);                  // nullReferenceException
   solvers->push_back(new InformedSolver1(input));
   solvers->push_back(new InformedSolver2(input));
}
```

That should be all the relevant information.
Let me know if you have any ideas as to what is causing this/ how to fix it!
Thanks.

Edit:
Added BasicSolver constuctor and dependency methods by comment request
also a little background: this is a Sudoku solver for an AI class

```
BasicSolver::BasicSolver(string input)
{
   peers = new vector<Peer*>();
   squares = new vector<Square*>();
   unsolved = new vector<Square*>();
   solved = new vector<Square*>();
   createStructure(input);
   original = input;
   mistakes = 0;
}

void BasicSolver::createStructure(string input)
{
   try
   {
       createEmptyStructure(peers, squares, unsolved);
      //Parse the puzzle and assign input to squares
      int numCharsToRead = MAX_SQUARES;   //makes sure vector isn't outside its range
      if (input.length() < MAX_SQUARES)   //makes sure string isn't outside its range
         numCharsToRead = input.length(); 
      for (int i = 0; i < numCharsToRead; i++)
      {
         if(input[i] != '.')
            insertValue(input[i], (*squares)[i], unsolved);
      }
   }
   catch(exception e)
   {
      throw e;
   }
}

void BasicSolver::createEmptyStructure(vector<Peer*> *workingPeers, vector<Square*> *workingSquares, vector<Square*> *workingUnsolved)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PEERS; i++)
    {
        workingPeers->push_back(new Peer());
    }
   for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++)
   {
      try
      {
          workingSquares->push_back(new Square('.'));

         //Adding the square to its corresponding peers
         (*workingPeers)[i / MAX_ROWS]->addSquare((*workingSquares)[i]); //adds the square into its appropriate row of peers
         (*workingPeers)[(i % MAX_ROWS) + COL_OFFSET]->addSquare((*workingSquares)[i]); //adds the square into its appropriate column of peers
         int tempBoxCol = (i % MAX_ROWS) / MAX_BOX_COLS; //returns the box column (0,1,2)

         if ((i / MAX_ROWS) < BOX_ROW_WIDTH) //if its box is in the first row
         {
             (*workingPeers)[tempBoxCol + BOX_OFFSET]->addSquare((*workingSquares)[i]);
         }
         else if ((i / MAX_ROWS) < (2 * BOX_ROW_WIDTH)) //if its box is in the second row
         {
             (*workingPeers)[BOX_ROW_WIDTH + tempBoxCol + BOX_OFFSET]->addSquare((*workingSquares)[i]);
         }
         else //if the box is in the third row
         {
             (*workingPeers)[2 * BOX_ROW_WIDTH + tempBoxCol + BOX_OFFSET]->addSquare((*workingSquares)[i]);
         }
      }
      catch(exception e)
      {
         throw e;
      }
   }
   *workingUnsolved = *workingSquares;
}
```

Edit2:
Personal tests
add these lines:

```
vector<BasicSolver*>* test = new vector<BasicSolver*>();
test->push_back(temp);
```

before

```
solvers->push_back(temp);
```

and they execute fine, I also notice that during runtime solvers is listed as outside of scope even though it is a protected variable of BasicSolver.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be allocating everything dynamically...

Comment: @zenith I know this is kind of overboard for how simple it is but I wanted to make it easier to add solutions later on, the solvers variable being dynamic is a remnant from my troubleshooting.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations on? If so, the `new` might not be happening until the next line. If you can already see the value of `temp` in your debugger, then this isn't the problem.

Comment: @TheDark I can see the value of temp before hitting step over on the the first push_back

Comment: in code you provided nothing wrong here

Comment: Could be a buffer overrun corrupting `solvers`. I just tried your code with some simple classes and it behaved as expected. Can you post your BasicSolver constructor?

Comment: @TheDark I added the constructor and its direct dependency methods.

Comment: In debugging some more I notice that solvers is listed as out of scope, but only during runtime. It is a protected variable of BasicSolver.

Comment: Did you mean `PuzzleSolver`? One other possibility is that the `this` pointer is NULL - how are you calling `createPuzzle`

Comment: @TheDark the caller did not have PuzzleSolver instantiated, thanks for suggesting that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the calling source did not have PuzzleSolver properly instantiated.
Thanks to @TheDark for suggesting I check that!